# Remove weird space from xml node (xPath/xQuery)

Tags: xml, xpath, unicode, xquery

I'm using Web-Harvest to scrap a website and generate xml file with data.

I'm having ugly nodes like `<name> </name>`, using normalize-space() didn't help so I opened the file in Hex view, and I found it corresponds to 'c2a0'. I looked arround for a solution, but no one helped...

To sum up, what I want is to remove that weird space (using xquery or xpath1/2), so I can get an empty node `<name/>`

ps: the used encoding is 'iso-8859-1'

Comment: Are you sure of the encoding? C2A0 is no-break space in UTF-8, which makes kind of sense.

Comment: @forty-two, well, the html source is in 'iso-8859-1' and my config and xml settings are 'iso-8859-1'... and it gives the space you see here `<name> </name>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `translate` to remove certain characters. And utf8 c2a0 is the character U+00A0, hexadecimal 0xA0 is 160, so you can use `codepoints-to-string(160)` to get a string with the space.

Together:

```
translate(your node text, codepoints-to-string(160), "")
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me, I still getting the weird space `<name> </name>`

Comment: Then perhaps you also have the wrong encoding settings. Try `replace(text, codepoints-to-string((194, 160)), "")`  (194 is 0xC2)

Comment: Appologies, I was manipulating the wrong text, that's why your first solution didn't work. But It is now. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: BTW, can you give links where you found about `c2a0 is U+00A0` and `0xA0 is 160`

Comment: c2a0 is listed on this [page](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) (actually I  just put c2a0 into google and that page was the first result). And 0xA0 as 160 is simply a  hexadecimal to decimal conversion, and any calculater can do it. (I used qalculate, since it is really amazing for unrelated reasons). But actually it should be possible to do it in your head, since A is 10 and 0 is 0,  so 0xA0 is 10*16+0.